# Using git or other version control tools on a shared host

Tags: git, shared-hosting

I am using a shared host for a project, in this host I have SSH access and ftp, but git is not available in SSH commands. How can I use git to develop my project there? if there is a way at all!

Comment: Apparently, git is not installed on this shared host. Install it and the command should be available through SSH.

Comment: I do not think he/she can install git as it is shared hosting. @OP you need to ask your provider to provide git. Alternatively you can take a bitbucket account which gives you free private repositories. So you keep your code there and download/upload zips of your repository to shared server if your provider does not help you.

Comment: I would but I can't even gcc is not available there so how can I?

Comment: I would also recommend to have a look at linode.com as it is cheap and you can have your own linux VMs and everything if you know how to administer a linux machine. Even digital ocean is worth a look. Get root access for $5/mo or $10/mo whichever suits you.